# MongoDB Aggregation: How to pick first doc from each bucket?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My aggregation stages look like:

```
[
  { $match: { ...someFilters } },
  { $sort: { createdOn: -1 } },
  { 
    $bucket: { 
      groupBy: $somePropertyInDoc,
      output: {
        DO_SOMETHING_TO_PICK_FIRST_DOC_IN_THE_BUCKET
      }
    } 
  }
]
```

I am assuming that buckets are arrays of documents which are transformed based on what is specified in the output property.

Is there any way to pick/output the first document from each bucket?

Comment: Your question could be better explained with a sample dataset and the expected output

Comment: Can't do that without sharing something that I can't. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output field takes accumulator operators, so you can use `$first` like:

```
{$bucket:{
    ...
    output: {document: {$first:"$$ROOT"}}
    ...
}}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2yOQDxosV-i)